# What Richfaces 4.0 has to offer for mobile development?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, mobile-website, oracle-adf

Richfaces 4.0 looks good with all optimizations. It is supposedly enhanced for mobile development. I wanted to know what additional features it offers for mobile development. How is it compared to Oracle ADF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [roadmap](http://community.jboss.org/thread/165592) , the mobile and tablet support is planned to be included in Richfaces 4.1 .

You can follow the  [Meeting Minutes and Transcripts of the Richfaces team meeting](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/richfacesteammeetinginformation)  for the richfaces development progress. On the [29-June-2011 meeting](http://people.redhat.com/~manderse/irc.freenode.org/meetings/richfaces/2011/richfaces.2011-06-29-15.04.log.html) , Mobile support  and [an example application showing mobile device UI options for RichFaces](https://github.com/richfaces/tweetstream) were mentioned .